# 406 Status Code

Tags: error-code

My website is opening very well but in the Moz tool, it is showing that my all webpages have a status code 406.  The web address is: https://fobtoronto.ca/

How to solve the issue?

Comment: Since MOZ is using a utility that emulates a browser, it's possible that their utility doesn't is asking for a response that your webserver isn't sending .  See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/406

Comment: A 406 is usually caused by an `Accept` request header that is very specific.   I cant replicate your server returning such a response, even with a nonsense content type.  I tried the command line `curl -s -v -H "Accept: text/html" https://fobtoronto.ca/compatible-key-fob-types/` which returns a `200 OK` status.

Comment: The  406 Not Acceptable client error response code indicates that the server cannot produce a response matching the list of acceptable values defined in the request's proactive content negotiation headers, and that the server is unwilling to supply a default representation.for causes and fixes refer following site:https://zendenwebdesign.com/blog-news/causes-and-fixes-for-406-error-not-acceptable/